# Error when trying to fix

Tags: apache, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5.5

This is about fixing an issue: LEVERAGE BROWSER CACHING(expiration not specified)

I added the following lines of code in .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>
```

It works perfectly on server but on localhost, it says

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You can enable `mod_expires` on your local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>
</ifmodule>
```

If it will be working it means mod_expires is not active on your server